# Alert dialog coming twice when changing from one tab two another tab in android

Tags: android

> I am developing one app related to call block.
>    I have created one
>   dashboard activity with "three" fragment tabs. Those are like call log
>   tab, block tab and settings tab. I want to check the name field
>   condition at settings tab if valid moving to another tab otherwise
>   showing alert "please enter valid name". If valid name it is going to
>   another tab successfully. But the name is not valid i want to show
>   alert dialog and stay at settings tab. But i am getting twice alert
>   box "please enter valid name". i have checked sites but i am unable to
>   get the solution, please help me thanks in advance.

---

My code is here:

---

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment{
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private View view;
private EditText et_consumerName;
DashboardActivity activity;
private static final String TAG = "SettingsFragment";

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = (DashboardActivity) context;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    activity = null;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment_new, container, false);
    et_consumerName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_consumerName);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) activity.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            // when user click on edit text then save button enable and
            // i am getting shared preference boolean value.
            boolean isSettingsChanged = TCPAApplication.mPref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_SETTINGS_CHANGED, false);

            if (isSettingsChanged) {
                int settingsPage = 2;
                String consumerNam = et_consumerName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUGLINES) Log.e(TAG, "counsumer name is " + consumerNam);
                if (!isConsumerNameValid(consumerNam)) {

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    enterFullNameAlert(getString(R.string.please_enter_firstname_and_lastname));

                    TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(settingsPage);
                    tab1.select();

                }
            } else {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected (TabLayout.Tab tab){

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected (TabLayout.Tab tab){

            }


        }
    });
    return view;
}

       private boolean isConsumerNameValid(String fName) {
           if (fName.length() > 0 && fName.contains(" ")) {
               return true;
           }

           return false;
       }
   }

    public void enterFullNameAlert(String msg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setTitle("Settings");


        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

            }
        });

        try {
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `onTabSelected` check for which tab and process accordingly.

Comment: Check `if(dialog==null) {dialog = alertDialog.create();  dialog.show();}`

Comment: I tried you sent code Piyush, still it is showing alert twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved alert dialog twice problem. Thanks for giving response all.

---

I have taken two global variables and done the below process.

```
private Boolean dialogShownOnceFullName = false;
private Dialog mdialog;
private int settingsPage = 2;


public void enterFullNameAndDisplayNameAlert(String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialog.setTitle("Settings");


    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(settingsPage);

        }
    });

    try {
        mdialog = alertDialog.create();
        if (!mdialog.isShowing() && !dialogShownOnceFullName) {
            mdialog.show();
            dialogShownOnceFullName = true;
        }

        mdialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialogShownOnceFullName = false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"take a global int for position of tab"
 in onTabSelected method check

```
if(globalposition==systemTabPosition)
  {
      if(checkcondition)
      {
      tabOther.select();
      globalPosition=position;
      }
      else
     enterFullNameAlert();
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the above code, this not working to me, any way thanks for your response.